# Low FPS on what should be a good laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, fps

Specifications:

Model: ASUS N56JR-EH71
 CPU: Intel i7-4700 HQ 2.40 GHz
 GPU: Geforce GTX 760m
 RAM: 12.0 GB
 OS: Windows 8.1
 Resolution (monitor) 1920 x 1080 with a 60 Hertz refresh rate.

Benchmarks:
Shadow of Mordor - Highest settings: 24 FPS

I have done the following:

Got my battery plan on high performance.

Updated GPU drivers

Regularly use CCleaner to clean up files, occasionally defrag.

Made sure my Nvidia settings were set for performance.

I close down unnecessary programs before gaming.

NOTE: Whenever I check using taskmanager, nothing but the disk ever gets close to 100%.

I try to play Starwars Battlefront and sometimes it is smooth, other times it is terrible. I do **not** have it anywhere near full graphics, and I assumed this would make it 60 fps at least, but no. Other games like Warframe suffer as well, though Warframe only occasionally drops to the 20s in FPS for a second and then goes back to 40-50.

Last time I was having problems I am pretty sure it was dust, since I dusted and it rectified itself. However, I have dusted the vent many times and no change this time around. I have **not** taken the laptop apart to dust it because I have never done such a thing and am afraid of not being able to put it back together.

Suggestions? This is driving me crazy. Shouldn't this laptop perform better? Or am I expecting too much?

Comment: What resolution do you use to play games? (external monitor?) How are your temperatures? If it gets too hot the GPU/CPU  might underclock to keep itself cool, resulting in FPS drops.

Comment: Editing now. Also, the temps get up to the 90 cs at the highest.

Comment: Are you playing this game online? If so network lag might be an issue. Also 12GB is an odd amount of RAM, does it have 16GB and the GPU uses 4GB of the system RAM?

Comment: what is your native display resolution? Nvidia states that around 97C is the max temperature but getting close to it will usually have performance inpact and drops and your laptop night shut off unexpectedly. I think it's to be expected that it will run modern games at around 30-50FPS even on medium or lower settings considering the resolution and temperature.

Comment: @Burgi Yeah it is odd. Yes, I know network lag would cause issues but not with FPS (though it does depend on how the game was made). In my experience connection doesn't effect FPS, at least not for all other games I play. No, not to my knowledge the computer properties says 12.

Comment: @Spokey Yeah I am totally open to the possibility that this laptop might not have the cooling capabilities needed to run such programs at 60+, it's just it has performed better beforehand (one of the reasons I think it is a dust issue or a driver). The native display on my laptop is listed in the post now.

Comment: If you have a hybrid graphics setup - an Intel solution for non-gaming, and your nVidia solution for gaming - then you want to make sure that when you launch the game that you are using your nVidia graphics.  Look in your nVidia control panel options for that kind of setting.

Comment: @headkase Thanks man, but yeah I knew about that. It is definitely using Nvidia.

Comment: It would be nice if you could show us actual benchmarks from games/benchmarking software (that way your performance can be compared to other benchmarks around the net). If you have games that have benchmarking modes that's fine, otherwise benchmark software would be something like Unigine Heaven, 3DMark, Futuremark and a couple more like these. For example, here we can see the expected performance of your card: http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-760M.92068.0.html Just to see how far your card is really behind others of the same model.

Comment: Speaking of which, this card seems to perform really badly at 1080p, really well at all 1366x768. Have you tried lowering the game's resolution setting?

Comment: @Cestarian I added the only game that has a benchmark to my knowledge, Shadow of Mordor (it is still relevant since this game suffers too). I will try the resolution swap. Thanks again.

Comment: You can see from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7VfG4uam1Y 

That 24 average FPS is completely normal for your card on this game (OP said it runs at 26-32 FPS, it would make sense for the benchmark to try some more intense stuff than normal gameplay which would put the average fps slightly lower.) The GTX 860M seems to perform at avg 35FPS in this game at your settings. (And since it's a maxwell, on a specs page the GTX 860M is vastly superior to GTX 760M) http://www.game-debate.com/gpu/index.php?gid=2143&gid2=1245&compare=geforce-gtx-860m-2gb-vs-geforce-gtx-760m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it does not seem like this machine is performing much worse than expected, judging by these benchmarks http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-760M.92068.0.html the card performs really poorly at 1920x1080 resolution, but rather well at lower resolutions like 1366x768. Even skyrim (which is a really easy game to run) only runs at 30fps at 1080p, but seemingly around 60fps when it's on 1366x768 resolution. Even the original Crysis (the old one) runs like crap on this card at 1080p. So the problem is that you're stressing the card too much if you're running at 1080p. You assumed the performance would be comparable to the GTX 760 I believe, but the mobile (laptop) cards perform significantly worse than their desktop equivalents on all levels, it has been this way for ages. And since 760 is a kepler card (nvidia really started taking leaps in mobile card performance, but only with the maxwell chipsets which were the nvidia 800 and 900 series, still nowhere near the desktop equivalents) you are even further disadvantaged. I too would have suspected this card to perfom better, but it is what it is.

If you look at the [minimum requirements](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/star-wars-battlefront-2015-alpha/12732/?p=r) for star wars battlefront that you showed me, you can see that the minimum requirement is actually an outrageously strong graphics card, GTX 660. GTX 760 isn't much more powerful than the 660, and here you have a 760M which is spec wise [significantly weaker](http://www.game-debate.com/gpu/index.php?gid=1245&gid2=591&compare=geforce-gtx-760m-vs-geforce-gtx-660) than both of these cards (660 has 760M beaten hard on all performance fronts, except power consumption).

Therefore, your performances seems normal to me. If you want to be 100% sure do benchmark, and look up what kind of performance other users with the same card are getting, [like here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHNARWMOw_0). As I said before, your card's performance drops considerably at high resolutions so lowering the games resolution might fix your problems (even if it won't look as nice, it will be much more playable).

Hope this helped. Sorry I didn't actually realize this sooner (I too thought the 760M should perform better than this, and was just as disillusioned as you about it)

Comment: I bought it about 1.5 years ago. I don't know if that is old, but whatever. Thanks for the reply! So... Warframe doesn't use a gpu? Or am I misunderstanding the term "cpu bound"? Starwars battle front has some serious graphics (http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/star-wars-battlefront-2015-alpha/12732/?p=r - minimun requirements). Mount and Blade runs great without a hitch. Age of Empires 3 did run without a hitch but recently had a minor FPS drop.  How do I check the clocks for the gpu? I will test the temps now.

Comment: The temps didn't get above 80, and my FPS was around 30-40 I think, definitely not 60 or over.

Comment: Uh quoting you here: Editing now. Also, the temps get up to the 90 cs at the highest. – CAA14 Feb 23 at 16:24;; but what I meant by CPU bound was that the GPU was performing at it's finest, however what caused lag was that the CPU was falling behind (couldn't keep up with the GPU, also known as bottleneck) for well, various reasons. Still, as I said before it could be that your card is keeping itself at sane temperatures by setting lowering it's performance setting (it can do this dynamically, on games it should be performing at the highest setting at all times)

Comment: Also I don't know how to check the performance mode on windows (on linux it's easy, there's a powermizer menu. Try googling "powermizer windows" see what you find, if you can keep track of it's 3 (or more, could be 4 or 5) performance modes and see that it is not performing at the highest levels in games, it is keeping it's performance low to avoid overheating and permanent damage (and if this is happening, it is doing so quite well). If you bought the laptop 1.5 years ago isn't it still warrantied? You might be able to get it looked at for free, techs are likely to do what I suggested as well

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized something all of us were failing to, I updated my answer, it is now actually correct, and the correct answer is: There is nothing wrong with your computer, it is just not as good as you had thought. This kind of behavior if the card was actually better than this would probably be because of what I answered earlier (dried up thermal paste). And if that is the case, use to your advantage that your laptop should still be warrantied and have it checked for you. Then again I might just be misunderstanding (you were rather vague about what fps you were getting)

Comment: Thank you so much man! My mind can finally rest on this issue. Changing the resolution helped tremendously. I didn't realize the laptop cards were different from the desktop ones, so that is good to know. Again, thank you so much for spending your time helping me get to the bottom of this! I just played SWBF and tweaked the settings and I can now get great FPS. I will probably still dust it thoroughly at some point, but now I know what to expect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Caa14. 
Go to your geforce website and make sure the drivers are up to date. There should be an app for it for you to adjust settings. As for how to check the capabilities of the moniter you should be able to find this by going to your control panel and looking up your hardware under administrative tools or at least the model number then Google it for more details.

As for viruses there are a few free antivirus software available such as malware bytes or avg... You can also get the yumi USB installer and get a boot level antivirus program you can install on a USB drive to keep hidden viruses from executing at boot as it runs from the usb drive instead of the HDD...

DO NOT INSTALL MORE THAN ONE ANTIVIRUS SOFTWARE ON A COMPUTER AT A TIME!!!

The tendency for antivirus software to bog a system down is enough many people disregard it entirely. Two increases the chances of this and can cause conflicts between them...

Also maybe as a standard never forget to make sure you don't have too much going on in the background. Close any unneeded software that may be configured to launch with the system such as open office or other stuff especially if it regularly reads or writes to the hard drive..
A good way to check for resource hogs is to open task manager by right clicking and opening from the context window.

Also you may have a display settings feature built into Windows but I forget as it has been a while since messing with control panel on that OS...

Also pretty sure the hardware specs you stated are for 64 bit systems only, have you made sure you are playing a 64bit version of the game... Sometimes this may require a patch from the company to get 32bit games to run on 64bit systems...

Comment: Yes, I know it is 64-bit. Thank you so much for this reply. Quick questions: I have Kapersky and Malwarebyes, though I do not have malwarebyes active. Could this create a problem? Also, do you mean opening taskmanager as administrator? As far as the display setting feature, what should I be looking to change, or should I be? I have updated the post with my computer model and a note on what I see when using taskmanager. Thanks again.

Comment: It is possible for kaspersky to false flag Mbytes still....look for your displays native resolution then do not exceed it otherwise it has to be reprocessed and downscaled.also as comments have stated you should look at your RAM. If you are using unmatching sets the system will underclock them both to the lowest speed they both share...

Answer (score -1):

I would make sure that you aren't sending too much info to the display you are using.. Its a laptop and setting graphics above the screen's actual resolution could cause a bottleneck of sorts...check your hardware limits sending 4k data to a 720x1080 is a waste of processing power as it would need to scale this back down....
....with a 45hz refresh limited display sending 60fps could be too high...

Remember your lucky if your eyes can see 30fps....

also not sure if your playing online with low speed connection the issue would be present in other ways as well....viruses can cause these issues as well

Comment: Well, I can tell a huge difference between 60 and 30 lol, unless the Warframe FPS counter is way off. Either way, virus problems are basically impossible to manually detect on purpose to my knowledge, though it does depend on what it is doing. Where do I check the graphic resolution setting? If you are speaking about in-game, I have it set to my monitor's resolution, and I have SWBF set to 77%. I would make it lower but then It gets intolerably blurry. Where do I find this "refresh-rate" you speak of? Thanks for responding so quickly to my post!